# Hidden line numbers

Tags: cross-referencing, line-numbering

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lineno}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Hidden Line Number}\label{cha:hln}
\linenumbers
%\begin{nolinenumbers}
One

Two\linelabel{two}\label{two}

Three

The sentence about \textbf{two}, page-\pageref{two}, chapter-\ref{cha:hln}, line number-\lineref{two}

%\end{nolinenumbers}
\end{document}
```

That I want what to do, hide linenumbers. If it possible?

[image]

Comment: `\nolinenumbers` at the right place switches them off , `\linenumbers` will reenable them

Comment: Add to \nolinenumbers -- Package lineno Error: \linelabel without \linenumbers

Comment: Of course, you can't use a `\linelabel` when there is no linenumber ;-)

Comment: Never end a paragraph with `\\ ` all the `\\ ` in your document are incorrect (and LaTeX gets very unhappy: `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 8--9` badness 10000 is _as bad as it gets_

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lineno}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Hidden Line Number}\label{cha:hln}
\linenumbers
%\begin{nolinenumbers}
\let\makeLineNumber\relax
One

Two\linelabel{twol}\label{two}

Three

The sentence about \textbf{two}, page-\pageref{two}, chapter-\ref{cha:hln}, line number-\lineref{twol}

%\end{nolinenumbers}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the viewer of this document expected to count the line number himself then? ;-) (Ok, it's only in line number `2`, so this should be possible ;-))

Comment: +1, but it's probably safer to save the meaning of `\makeLineNumber` for later use.

Comment: @karlkoeller I assume the real example it's inside a group:-)